# the graph of any continuous map is closed on Banach spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, solution-verification, closed-graph

> $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces. Prove that the graph of any continuous
>   map $T: X \to Y$ is closed.

Is below a correct solution?

We have to show that  any sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ in $\mathcal{G}(T) = \{(x,y) : x\in X \ \ \& \ \ \ Tx=y\}$ converges to a point $(x,y)$ in $\mathcal{G}(T)$.

Let's take a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ in $\mathcal{G}(T)$. Since $X\times Y$ is Banach, we have that $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$ in $X\times Y$. It remains to show that $Tx=y$.

We have that by completeness of $X$, that $x_n \to x$ for an $x \in X$, and by the continuity of $T$, $Tx_n \to Tx$,  also we have that $Tx_n \to y$. So choose $N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$, $\|Tx_n - Tx\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\|Tx_n - y\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So

$$\|Tx-y\|\le\|Tx_n - Tx\|+\|Tx_n - y\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

Comment: This is a standard result known as the closed graph theorem.

Comment: This is not the essential part of the closed graph theorem. What OP wants to prove is the easy direction. The difficult direction is the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof needs some refinement.

In this proof, you don't need that $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, it suffices that they are normed spaces. Now you take a sequence $(x_n, Tx_n)$ in $\mathcal{G}(T)$ and *assume* that this sequences converges to $(x, y) \in X \times Y$. What we have to show is $(x, y) \in \mathcal{G}(T)$.
By definition of the convergence, it is clear that $x_n \to x$ and $Tx_n \to y$. But since $T$ is assumed to be continuous, $Tx_n$ converges to $Tx$. Thus $y = Tx$ and the graph is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is messy.

We want to prove that if $\mathcal G(T) \ni(x_n, y_n) \to (x,y)$, then $(x,y)\in\mathcal G(T)$.